# How to return a 200 ok status programmatically to ajax request in PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, http-headers, http-status-codes

I ask this question for the comment of this answer:

https://serverfault.com/questions/104648/is-this-http-servers-issue/104679#104679

**EDIT**

I missed an important point,should also keep the connection not closed.

You guys can smell I'm trying to figure out how long polling actually works.

Comment: This is not the question you should be asking...

Answer (score 2):

200 OK happens as long as nothing goes wrong.  So you should always get that status as long as the HTTP request succeeds. No need to do anything special.

Comment: True, this includes completing the process or flush something to the browser before the request time-out.

Comment: @o.k.w: +1 **completing the process** should be bolded.

Answer (score 1):

As of PHP 5.4.0 you can use [`http_response_code()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php):

```
<?php http_response_code(200); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

to complete hitautodestruc post, with PHP <5.4 you could also set

```
<?php header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"); ?>
```

..but sending 200 code in any way is useless, since it is already sent by default when request completes, and if none error occurs otherwise on server-side (5xx)

maybe you are looking for something like this ?

```
HTTP/1.1 206    Partial Content
```